# DataWeave Transformation: Flatten nested json objects

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I would like to transfer the following input to output JSON format.

And keys should be dynamic. I have other payloads with unique JSON structures.

How can I solve this?

**Input:**

```
{"Report_Entry": [{
"Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
"Amount": "22",
"Lines": [{
"Project": "Proj1"
},{
"Project": "Proj2"
}],
"Amendments": [{
"Name": "Amd 1",
"Status": "Approved"
},{
"Name": "Amd 2",
"Status": "Approved"
}]
}]
}
```

**Output:**

```
[{
"Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
"Amount": "22",
"Project": "Proj1",
"Name": "Amd 1",
"Status": "Approved"
},{
"Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
"Amount": "22",
"Project": "Proj1",
"Name": "Amd 2",
"Status": "Approved"
},{
"Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
"Amount": "22",
"Project": "Proj2",
"Name": "Amd 1",
"Status": "Approved"
},{
"Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
"Amount": "22",
"Project": "Proj2",
"Name": "Amd 2",
"Status": "Approved"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code first compiles a list of keys all the array elements. (I assumed `Report_Entry` array elements maintain the same structure as the first element, if that is not the case, it can be passed as an argument to the `mapArrays` function.)

It recursively traverses each report Entry and adds the object entries of each array element until it reaches the final array in report Entry. Then it aggregates all it to the final result. Used `flatMap` to flatten the array output and `--` to remove the array elements from the reportEntry on  the final output.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var arrayKeys = 
    namesOf(payload.Report_Entry[0] filterObject ((value, key) -> value is Array ))

fun mapArrays (reportEntry, index, prevItems={}) = 
    if (index == sizeOf (arrayKeys)-1)
        reportEntry[arrayKeys[index]] map ((item) -> 
            (reportEntry -- arrayKeys)
            ++ prevItems
            ++ item
        )
    else
       reportEntry[arrayKeys[index]] flatMap ((item) -> mapArrays (reportEntry, index+1, prevItems ++ item))
---
payload.Report_Entry flatMap ((item) -> mapArrays (item, 0))
```

Comment: This works, however there are other ways to get the list of keys that have array values that express better the intention. You could use filterObject, or pluck/filter.

Comment: Fair enough. Changed to use `namesOf` and `filterObject`

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is only one element in Report_Entry. Nesting maps on lines and amendments will give you the combination of elements required.  Because nesting maps returns nested arrays, `flatMap()` or `flatten()` are required at the top to flatten the result of the two maps.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var root=payload.Report_Entry[0]
---
root.Lines 
    flatMap ((line, line_index) -> 
        root.Amendments map ((amendment, amendment_index) -> 
        {
            Accepted_Currencies: root.Accepted_Currencies,
            Amount: root.Amount
        }
        ++ line 
        ++ amendment )
    )
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
    "Amount": "22",
    "Project": "Proj1",
    "Name": "Amd 1",
    "Status": "Approved"
  },
  {
    "Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
    "Amount": "22",
    "Project": "Proj1",
    "Name": "Amd 2",
    "Status": "Approved"
  },
  {
    "Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
    "Amount": "22",
    "Project": "Proj2",
    "Name": "Amd 1",
    "Status": "Approved"
  },
  {
    "Accepted_Currencies": "USD; EUR",
    "Amount": "22",
    "Project": "Proj2",
    "Name": "Amd 2",
    "Status": "Approved"
  }
]
```

Comment: Aled: Is it possible to update logic to avoid specifying field names (Lines and Amendments)? I want to reuse the same code in other places where these fields do not exist.
I made minor changes in code:

%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload.Report_Entry map ((value, index) -> 
value.Lines  flatMap ((line, line_index) -> 
        value.Amendments map ( (amendment, amendment_index) -> 
        value mapObject ((value1, key1, index1) -> 
        {
            ((key1): value1) if (!(value1 is Array))
        })  ++ line ++ amendment 
))))

Comment: See the other answer from @sudhish_s.